# Generic filter using SimpleListFilter

Tags: python, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm customizing a filter but would leave it generic but could only make for a case.

I have to create multiple filters but want to use only one class. I can create a class to use in different types of filters?

```
class MyModelCustomizeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

title = u'' #It can be parameterized?
parameter_name = u'' #It can be parameterized?

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return (
        ('1', ('Activated')), #It can be parameterized?
        ('0', ('Negate')),
        ('all', ('All')),
    )

def choices(self, cl):
    for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
        yield {
            'selected': self.value() == lookup,
            'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                self.parameter_name: lookup,
            }, []),
            'display': title,
        }

def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    if self.value() in ('0', '1'):
        return queryset.filter(status=self.value())
    elif self.value() == None:
        return queryset.filter(status=None)
```

I can parameterize **parameter_name**, **title** and **values lookup**?